# KVO or how to listen for a property changes from outside in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2, key-value-observing

I have a instance with a property which I want to listen for updates from other instance.

For example class Menu has a property badgeCount, I want to listen for any updates for badgeCount for example when badgeCount is changed. I want my ViewController to have callback after badgeCount is modified to know actual data.

In objective was KVO that I can use for listed property, how can I use KVO in Swift. I am new in Swift.

Comment: You can use KVO too, but you would have to use NSObject and such. Instead I suggest you to use notifications or roll out your own change observation mechanism. Both options are fine and depending on situation you may prefer one over another.

Comment: Have a look at the Bond framework, they have an Observable type that may help you: https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use KVO in swift, there are two requirements :

- The class you want to do KVO on must inherit from NSObject (or any NSObject subclass)
- The property you need to observe must be marked as `dynamic`

a code example would be:

```
class Menu: NSObject {
  dynamic var badgeCount: Int = 0
}
```

And then, you can use the usual `menuInstance.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "badgeCount", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)`

But this solution is not very much *swifty*.

---

Better solutions are (not an exhaustive list):

Use swift's `didSet/willSet` to call some callback

```
class Menu {
  var badgeCount: Int = 0 {
     didSet {
        badgeCountChangedListener(badgeCount)
     }
  }

  init(badgeCountChangedListener: (Int -> Void)) {
    self.badgeCountChangedListener = badgeCountChangedListener
  }

  private let badgeCountChangedListener: (Int -> Void)
}
```

Use [RxSwift's](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) `Variable` type

```
class Menu {
   let badgeCount = Variable(0)
}

// and from where you observe
menuInstance.badgeCount.subscribeNext { badgeCount in
    print(badgeCount)
}
```

Comment: thanks, but seems I can't add menuInstance.addObserver, there is even no method for instance called addObserver

Comment: as noted in the answer  >The class you want to do KVO on must inherit from NSObject